# Since when has the formula $I = \frac{b h^3}{12}$ (second moment of area) has been discovered and applied in building construction?

Tags: material-science, history, elasticity

A question about history of physics: since when and by who has the formula for the [second moment of area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_moment_of_area)

$$I = \frac{b h^3}{12}$$

been discovered? When has it started being applied in building construction?

[image]

**It basically states that we can minimize the bending of a wooden beam by having a taller height and a narrower width, for a given fixed volume of wood.**

In (French) houses from early XXth century, floor joists typically have a **square** cross-section (which is not really logical), whereas nowadays, wooden floor joists are often much taller than they are wide, which is more logical from the formula above for the second moment of area $I$.

Why is it so? Hasn't the formula for $I$ been discovered one century ago?

Comment: *A question about history of physics* -> https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you @Ghoster, but since there is the [history] tag here, it might fit here as well.

Comment: Did you read the description of the “history” tag?